# Safari not rerendering keyframes on window resize

Tags: css, safari, media-queries, transform, translate-animation

I'm using CSS3 to translate and fade in an element to different locations depending on two different screen widths with @media queries. It works exactly as I expect it to in both the latest Chrome and Firefox. The problem comes with Safari 10. When the window is resized, regardless of whether the @media query is triggered again, the 100% keyframe is not rerendered. The div with the "animate-div" class stays right where it last translated to in a fixed position from the initial page load. Here's a snippet of what I'm talking about. Thanks!

And yes, I have a viewport HTML tag in the head.

```
.animate-div {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: divIn 2800ms forwards ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    @keyframes divIn {
        0% {
            height: 12vw;
            width: 12vw;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate(44vw, calc(50vh - 6vw));
        }
        50% {
            height: 16vw;
            width: 16vw;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(42vw, calc(50vh - 8vw));
        }
        100% {
            height: 17vw;
            width: 17vw;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(2vw, 2vw);
            margin-bottom: 3vw;
        }
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    @keyframes divIn {
        0% {
            height: 26vw;
            width: 26vw;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate(37vw, calc(50vh - 13vw));
        }
        50% {
            height: 30vw;
            width: 30vw;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(35vw, calc(50vh - 15vw));
        }
        100% {
            height: 30vw;
            width: 30vw;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(35vw, 1vw);
            margin-bottom: 2vw;
        }
    }

}
```